# About existence of extensión of a function.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A,B$ sets and $f:A \to B$ an inyective function. Then exists $C$ a set and $g: C \to B$ biyective function such that $A \subseteq C$ and $g(x)=f(x)$ for all $x \in A$

I know that this question is silly, since that extension function can seem intuitive, but I cannot get a proof of that.

Comment: Your question is not so bad, it is interesting.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Let
$$D=\{x\in B\;:\;\forall y\in A\;\; f(y)\ne x\}$$

and
$$C=A\cup D$$

If $ D $ is empty, $ f $ is bijective.

Assume $ D\ne \emptyset $ and
define the map $ g : C \to B \; $  by $ :$

for $ x\in C $,

$$g(x)=f(x) \;\; if \; x\in A$$
and
$$g(x)=x \; \; if \; x\in D$$

$ g $ is clearly a bijection from $ C $ on $ B$.

Comment: Your answer is wrong. Consider $A$ the set of even natural numbers, $B$ the natural numbers and $f(n)=2n$ for all $n \in A$. Then $2 \in A \cap D$, thus, if $g$ is well defined we have $f(2)=2$, contradiction.

Comment: @Jose $ 2 $ is not in $ D $.

Comment: $2$ is an even natural number, then $2 \in A, B$, if $f(n) = 2$ for some $n \in A$, then $2=2n,\, n=1$ but $1$ is not even, contradiction, therefore $f(n) \neq 2$ for all $n \in A$, thus $2 \in D$.

Comment: @Jose So, $ g(2)=2$. where is the problem.

Comment: The answer given by hamam_Abdallah is essentially correct, only that you also have to choose $D$ in such a way that $D$ and $A$ are disjoint. This is never a problem because we can choose $D$ completely freely. Consider the example given by @Jose: Instead of letting $D$ be the set of all numbers $n$ which are not multiples of $4$, let it be the set of all pairs $(n,n)$ where n is not a multiple of $4$. Then $A$ and $D$ are disjoint, and we can define $g(n):=2n$ for $n\in A$ and $g(n,n)=n$ for $(n,n)\in D$.